# Include file <sched_yield.h> not found on my RHEL 5

Tags: c++, linux, rhel5

I'm using a fairly old dev environment, when I "man sched_yield" I can see this man page, but if I try to use it,

$cat m.cpp

```
#include<sched_yield.h>
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

g++ will say:

```
error: sched_yield.h: No such file or directory
```

So should I install any extra yum package on this box? How to fix it?

Comment: The man page is likely for the `sched_yield` function. It should also mention what header you actually need to include. (`sched.h`?)

Comment: IIRC rhel5 have it declared in `<pthread.h>` and  `<sched.h>`.

Comment: RHEL5 isn't updated at all any more (well okay there's ELS for another couple of years). Insert obligatory emphasis on the importance of upgrading when possible. I've been trying to get customers off RHEL6 for years.

Comment: Also see [How do I find packages with Yum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85715/56041) and [Searching for packages using apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111377/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I usually `fgrep -rw` them in `/usr/include` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The manpage I'm looking at](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield) says `#include <sched.h>`.

It's the *function* that's called `sched_yield`.